# How can I connect to Apache James' user repository and retrieve a list of users through Java code?

Tags: java, apache, jmx, mail-server, james

How can I connect to Apache James' user repository and retrieve a list of users through Java code? Is there a way using the Apache James api?

Thank You
Chris

Answer (score 2):

The answer is rather simple if you know how.

Have a look at the Java Management eXtension (JMX) and study the [UserManagementMBean](http://james.apache.org/server/3/apidocs/index.html).

-> edit:
the more concise [link](http://james.apache.org/server/3/apidocs/org/apache/james/user/lib/UserManagement.html) to the implementation of UserManagementMBean

Currently, I can't provide code samples because I'm a JMX beginner myself at the moment.
Perhaps you could add some links to [my question about James about Apache James learning resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418249/apache-james-learning-resources).

Comment: surely it's possible to do something like: [Let's add a few users before moving on. To do that, telnet to localhost on port 4555 with the command telnet localhost 4555. You can log in with the root user name and password.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-james1/index.html) except that, instead of adding users, retrieve a list of users.