# Apache James Learning Resources

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-mail, james

The plan is to create a list of [Apache James](http://james.apache.org) learning resources, involving a wide a range of aspects from setting it up to using API from java.

If you read this and have some great tutorial at your fingertips, please drop a line or two.

I'll start with

- [The Official Apache James Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/james/FrontPage)
- an article by IBM: [Working with James, Part 1: An introduction to Apache's James enterprise e-mail server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-james1/index.html)

Comment: Which learning resources with Apache James as topic do you use on a regular basis or which do you think excel in some way?

Comment: the documentation seems lacking on this topic:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848285/james-not-picking-up-mysql-connector-jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848285/james-not-picking-up-mysql-connector-jar)

Comment: how about explaining [how to access messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961365/unable-to-send-mail-to-outside-domain-using-localhost-as-a-host-via-apache-james?rq=1) from James?

Answer (score 4):

Some more resources:

1. http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/james/james.html
2. http://blyx.com/public/docs/JAMES_2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For version 3, here is the best I have found so far :

http://james.apache.org/server/3/config.html (not very helpful, but it is something)

http://www.mail-archive.com/server-user@james.apache.org/ (see questions of others)

https://james.apache.org/mail.html (mailing lists - when no docs are available, bugging people may help or force them to write more documentation... Although even that doesn't seem to work with Apache...)

**If** I manage to make it work the way I want, I might put some instructions here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm PMC of James project.

We are working on making running James easier. So far :

- We managed to make running it easier by providing docker images (Have a look to dockerfiles on github and https://hub.docker.com/r/linagora/james-jpa-guice/ (for instance) for automatically built image... )
- We also made a CI system available for potential contributors : https://github.com/linagora/james-jenkins
- We are working hard to a new website, more appealing, and that better present the project.

I understand your concerns, and actually think myself the documentation and communication of the project is a bit unfriendly.

I bielieve that some tutorial might help. Could you please :

- Specify which use cases you are targetting (SMTP relay, IMAP server, integration of other applications with e-mails) and we can try to provide "tutorials".
- Don't hesitate to contribute to the project. On the mailing list. Or with contributions to the website.
- The right place to have such discussions is IMO the Apache James user mailing list.

Cheers,

Benoit