# james not picking up mysql connector jar

Tags: apache, configuration, james

I've tried doing a james [1] install on my amazon instance with MySQLas a back-end. I've  MySQL connector mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.zip,unzipped and copied it to conf/lib and lib/ but when I start james with: $ sudo bin/james start  it stops. Wrapper log shows:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

My james-database.properties looks like this:

```
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driverdatabase.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jamesdatabase.username= ** user name **
```

database.password= ** secret **vendorAdapter.database=MYSQL openjpa.streaming=false

I didn't change anything else.but james is not work.

Any helps ,Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/james/V3ConfigTutorial) says:

```
Using MySQL instead of Derby

Download the MySQL driver JAR from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html, and put the JAR file into your ./conf/lib folder. Change the database settings in ./conf/database.properties to the following values:

# MySQL JDBC database properties
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/james
database.username=jamesuser
database.password=password_for_jamesuser
vendorAdapter.database=MYSQL
openjpa.streaming=false

To add the JAR to the classpath, edit ./bin/setenv.sh as shown here:

# Add every needed extra jar to this
CLASSPATH_PREFIX=../conf/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
```

However, their versioning seems off, and, admittedly, these directions [don't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999233/apache-james-gives-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver).

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get mine apache-james-3.0-beta4 working setting `database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/james?create=true`

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply comes a little bit late but I just ran into this issue.

According to Eric Charles [answer](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.james.user/18802):

The conf/lib/*.jar loading in beta4 is buggy.

You need to edit the conf/wrapper.conf and change

```
'wrapper.java.classpath...=../conf/lib' to 
'wrapper.java.classpath...=../conf/lib/*' (add a /* after lib).
```

You can use a text editor or if you are using a script or something similar (Dockerfile in my case) to install James you can also edit it by going to the directory where wrapper.conf is located and execute:

```
sed -i "s/wrapper\.java\.classpath\.2=\.\.\/conf/wrapper\.java\.classpath\.2=\.\.\/conf\/lib\/\*/g" wrapper.conf
```

After this all jars in conf/lib should be loaded to the classpath next time James is started.